How to colloquially express indifference -preferably in an American Southern tongue-
I am looking for phrases that express indifference in order to translate a foreign poem.
It is a Greek phrase and literally translates into "None of my nails is burning" which means "I do not care".
It hides a certain temperament or passion; you wouldn't use it in a mundane scenario such as in a restaurant for example:

_Red or White wine sir?
_??None of my nails is burning.

No, that wouldn't make any sense, you use it in a heated argument especially if passion or love is involved so as to address to a loved one that hurt you or something of similar nature.

If you’re looking for something vulgar and typically insulting—both of the choices and to the individual being addressed—there’s always I don’t give a rat’s ass.

You give a real-life example of when you wouldn't use it; please give an example that does show its correct use. My first thought was "It's no skin off my nose," but that wouldn't make sense in response to "red or white"; it means more "that situation which might be supposed to upset me in fact does not." One extremely rural solution would be "don't make no never mind."

Protip, you can make any clause sound American Southern by prepending reckon to it--though this may not be as appropriate for more recent generations raised by the television, I reckon.

I guess this is different insofar as it's about regional English but colloquial indifference, indifferent resignation, i don't care adjective, don't care a X...

... don't have a X in this Y, don't make a ceremony of, nothing special, etc.

"an American southern tongue"? Do you mean in the southern American dialect? Also, what is a "foreign poem"?

I'm not sure if this still in use, but I've occasionally run across "makes no nevermind to me".

Does anyone in Southern US still say "It don't make no never mind to me" ? For "non-yokelly" BrE, just say "It's all the same to me".

...But I'm not clear on whether the sought term should imply contempt that anyone should care (hence contempt for whoever asked for your preference), OR genuine lack of preference and a willingness to let the asker make the choice on your behalf (whichever's easiest for him is fine, you don't mind).

You must supply a sample sentence of how it would be used, not of how it wouldn't.  And what qualities are you associating with the US South?  Genteel Kentucky Derby or Talladega racing?

After waiting a while, I'm going to go ahead and vote to close until this is clearer on exactly what shade of meaning is needed.

The classic is “Frankly, my dear, I don’t give a damn”, from Gone with the Wind.

I can see there are no southern American dialect speakers here except maybe...myself? But I wouldna pay it no mind. [Bear in mind I got that from my own speech "stuff" because I can code switch.]

Try this one, meaning you don't care about an outcome:

I don't have a dog in this fight.

It is folksy and commonly heard in most or all of the Southern states of the US.
I wouldn't use it to order random wine (try "Surprise me" for that), but it is fine for any kind of situation in which you wish to avoid expressing an opinion.

That's for an argument, not a choice of wine.

@Lambie As I note in my final sentence.

@Lambie: the OP specifically says the expression he wants to translate is not  used for a choice of wine.

@PeterShor Six of one, half a dozen of the other. Yep, I misread it.

It sounds like you're looking especially for a somewhat disingenuous expression, one that claims indifference or disinterest when in fact one is very emotionally charged. With that in mind, I think my top pick is:

"See if I care!" Merriam-Webster says it's "used in angry speech to say that you do not care at all about something." This carries a certain defiance or antagonism; it's phrased as something of a challenge or a dare.
A much less charged expression might be "It's no skin off my nose." M-W says "used to say that someone does not care or does not have a strong opinion about something." The emphasis here is on the speaker not being hurt by a proposed action (M-W's example is "Go if you like—it's no skin off my nose"). It might be an awkward phrase in response to a choice (like red or white wine), but one could conceivably say "It's no skin off my nose either way."

Neither of these is limited to the American South, but they're certainly appropriate for it. As others have suggested, you could simply rely on other phrases to establish local color.

Those are rude and not funny and too marked.

@Lambie Ah, maybe this is why the question needs clarifying. I didn't see any need that it be funny, and indeed "temperament ... passion ... so as to address to a loved one that hurt you" suggested to me that something heated was desired.

Good stuff. Another one along similar lines is “Do I look like I care?”

“Either one is fine.”
“Your choice—I’ll be happy either way.”
“Whatever.” This last expresses annoyance at being asked. There is no need to do that—you can be neutral but pleased either way.

There is an expression, which, if not issued from Southern American culture has  perhaps its root in American culture, as it might have been used first by Americans during WWII or earlier in the century; there is a variant of it, but I don't know if it is common in AmE.
(CrossIdiomas.com)  give a hoot
Quora
(Collins Dictionary) do not give a hoot
If you say that you don't give a hoot or don't care two hoots about something, you are emphasizing that you do not care at all about it.
Also "don't care two hoots about sth"

There is of course the popular version of it, "not to give a damn", which is informal too, but much more so, as I presume.
Other variants
(OLD)  not to care a hoot
(SOED) not to matter/… a hoot

That is rude and you wouldn't use it unless you wanted to be rude. -1

@Lambie You keep downvoting answers that are "rude". OP wants something that can be said in a heated argument, and sometimes rude things are said in heated arguments.

@pacoverflow As you phrase your comment, the readers might ask themselves whether you might not be saying that the tone of the answer also, and not only the proposed expression, was rude, which, of course, whether it is the answer or your say, I don't believe.

"I am looking for phrases that express indifference in order to translate a foreign poem". That does not mean rudeness.

@Lambie True, in the words you select out of the post nothing can have someone suppose that rudeness can be a factor. However, this comment and the answer it is found under show clearly that you are the only one not to be reading the OP entirely. Why you are hoping to have us  turn a blind eye alongside with you on what you choose to dismiss as non-existing is beyond my understanding.

give a hoot is not southern, at least nowadays.

@Lambie What do you mean by "nowadays"? If it is not southern, that is to say, that its origin is not the south, then  this is forever; perhaps "by not southern"  you mean that it is not used or not much used in the South; in this case where did you get that information? (Things like that about a region are difficult to know for people who haven't spent their whole life in it, unless they have access to the results of some linguistic inquiries.)

You sometimes manage to annoy me a lot. The expression to give or not give a hoot, I have known my whole life, hearing it from Americans from many different states/regions. It's something that I know; it is not information I obtained.

@Lambie Your English is not clear and you don't give those clarifications I ask, but instead you go off at a tangent and speak about something else that has nothing to do. I did not contest your knowledge of this expression.

@LPH STOP twisting words. You said: in this case where did you get that information about give a hoot? [by the way, it's that case, not this case]. You don't get it: I have lived in the SOUTH, and my mother was southern (from Tennessee) and my father was from Boston. And I have also lived in the NE. And spoken to tons of people from many states. give a hoot is not southern at all. My English is very clear.

Not nowadays. You don't know the meaning of not nowadays?


(Capmbridge Dictionary) couldn’t care less to not care at all:

I couldn't care less if he doesn't want to talk to me.


This expression seems to be considered as somewhat rude as an answer, for instance, to someone's request. It is used almost as much in AmE as it is in BrE.


Of course, In the South, we say "I could care less". No, it doesn't make any sense, but that's what we say.

This is rude. -1

@PhilSweet Nor is "I couldn't care less" immediately clear ; less than what? You have to imagine that the compared level is something like "than when I care the least for something".

@Lambie At least you are frank, -1. // "It hides a certain temperament or passion", temperament (OALD) : the tendency to get  emotional  and excited very easily and behave in an unreasonable way // Don't you think that "I don't care" is often enough pronounced in a rather rude manner, and don't you think that "None of my nails is burning" has to be a little sarcastic, and thereby a little rude ?

No, it's rude. If you want to be polite, you'd say: I really don't mind which you serve me. OR It makes no difference to me.

@Lambie Yes, it can be rude, although it doesn't have to be, and it can be said in a jocular tone, also; anyway, do you think that in a heated argument (OP's words) people  always remain very polite? For instance, your "I don't care" today (FSE chat) has been called by yourself "sarcastic" (I suppose you made up for the  tone of voice, absent from the written word): "Oh really? I didn't know that. (sarcastic) I don't care about random typos."; that is a little bit rude;  "you couldn't care less about typos": (mere emphasis).

@Lambie I suspect you use it in a far more restricted way than many of us. If my 98-year-old mom asked me "which do you want to watch - the news or baseball?" I couldn't care less would be a perfectly normal answer. It can be used dismissively as well, but not just that way.

Thinking about this a bit more, I'd probably say "honestly, I couldn't care less". I suppose honestly works as an ameliorator here. So we have a way to signal when we are not being dismissive.

@PhilSweet I just didn't think he wanted something rude. Just something unmarked OR southern.

In the American South of the 20th century, you can use

It/That don't make [me] no never mind. [Sometimes written "... nevermind"]

The Free Dictionary defines the phrase thusly:

colloquial I have no strong feelings or preference (about something) one way or the other.
A: "Where do you want to go for dinner?" B: "It don't make no never mind—wherever you want to go is fine."

A 1982 article published in the scholarly journal American Speech, Gerald L. Cohen writes:

American dialectal speech contains the expressions That don't make me no never mind and I don't pay that no never mind. The expressions occur in Ozark speech (which first drew my attention to them), but comments from my colleagues and students indicate that they are used too in Mississippi, South Carolina, Alabama, Kentucky, and West Virginia. They are thus found in the Ozarks, the deep South, the Appalachians, and possibly elsewhere. The expressions have also been used occasionally in movies and television programs, thereby reaching a national audience.

Cohen, G. L. (1982). That don’t make me no never mind. American Speech, 57(1), 76–79. https://doi.org/10.2307/455183 
Cohen goes on for a few pages on the geographic (rural American South) and age (older) demographics in which this phrase is more prevalent and gives a few examples of similar/related phrases.
A Reddit thread from earlier this year asked the meaning of the phrase "It don't make me no never mind." The answers indicate "It doesn't matter to me," but one also claims a connotation of "I think you're wrong but I can't stop you."

+1 If you want to sound southern, this.  Used multiple times in The Ladykillers.  Also Black Dynamite, several other movies.

Yes, this is right. So is the simpler: pay it no mind, also southern.

This one means it's the same to me:
Six of one, half a dozen of the other.

Said when you think that neither of two choices is better than the
other: "Should we give her chocolates or flowers?" "I don't know, it's
six of one and half a dozen of the other."

Cambridge Dictionary
The above expression is not particularly southern but it's neutral and polite.
Southern: Ah wouldna pay it no mind either way.
pay somethin' no mind=SOUTHERN.
Right, so I went looking for confirmation, and found it:

“Y’All Speak Southern?”
By Diane Hollern Harvey
The South is filled with words and expressions that are rarely heard
outside of the region. Would you understand what was happening if
someone was calling the hogs after cutting off the light? Would you be
afeared of a hant, or would you pay it no mind? While most of these
expressions are rarely heard outside of the South, southern English
has expanded beyond the South thanks to people moving in and out of
the region. If you have ever said hey to a friend instead of hi. or
said that you would be willing to tote or carry something, then you
were speaking “southern.”
Pay him/her no mind. Don't pay attention to him or her.

So, "I wouldna pay it no mind". = I would not pay attention to [whatever]. It's the same to me.
This is the ONLY answer with a southern flavor.

I believe you misread the question, which also becomes clear from the comments you put under the others' answers. OP is looking for an answer for situations explicitly NOT meant for situations like "red or white wine?". They are looking for answers that bring forth some temperament, so it's also okay to be rude

@Ivo "I am looking for phrases that express indifference"

@Ivo I wouldna pay it no mind. is southern.

I believe you've got so many negative votes because unfortunately you confuse the result of a comparison between TWO things, this result being "no difference" (said when you think that neither of two choices is better than the other) and "someone's attitude towards SOMEthing", that attitude  amounting to having no interest at all.

@LPH There is no specifically SOUTHERN way to express indifference. However, there is the one I made up using a southern way of talking. And since few around here would know those uses, they dv.

Now, your southern dialect addition makes sense, but it is an addition after all the downvotes. What you propose before that is a piece of twisted thinking. I do understand your thought process, but it is no good.

To say that you think that neither of two choices is better than the other does not at all mean that YOU don't care about the choice, nor is it a question of two things being compared (that is out of the blue). You have to get rid of that adage, it does not apply.

@LPH Twisted thinking is for sick people. six of one, half a dozen of the other expresses indifference. le même combat.

@LPH See the list (pay it no mind) from this academic. https://culturalcomparisonscom272.wordpress.com/american-northamerican-south/verbal-south/ It is most definitely not garbage but you ain't a yokel so you don't git it.
